# Quasar Framework - how to reset q-uploader in submit form

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

Good afternoon!
how to clear q-uploader in submit form?
I can't understand what is the reason..

there is a form

```
<q-form
    @submit="onSubmit">
```

in which there is an element

```
 <q-uploader
        label="Load files..."
        accept=".jpg"
        ref="uploader">
```

on submit form trying to clear q-uploader

```
const onSubmit = () => { uploader.value.reset() }
```

the uploader is not cleared - if I throw the button - and bind @click - then everything is cleared ...

Comment: `uploader` belongs to $refs object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

understood - what's the matter

q-uploader has

```
: disable = "count! = 0"
```

I previously send a request and, accordingly, disable - by assigning count = 1 (it's a little more complicated there - the number is used and not just a boolean value - not the point)

after successful request

```
count.value = 0
```

and, accordingly, `uploader.value.reset ()` - however, the q-uploader does not have time to unload and, accordingly, is not cleared

set a timeout

```
setTimeout (() => {uploader.value.reset ()}, 100)
```

but you don't like the solution - can someone suggest a more beautiful solution? any wait when q-uploader became available?